# How can I delete everything else from my txt except hungarian texts?

Tags: notepad++, regex, language, text-formatting

I have a localisation file from a game, and unfortunately, this file conain all localized language, but I only need is, the hungaryan texts from them.
I would like to make a video series from this game, and the realy grateful thing is, the game is transleted, but I can't use the texts in this format and I need help for I can delete everything from my txt, except hungarian text.
The key thing is on my file, after every "," character is a come the next language, forexample:

> "KEY","Spanish","English","German","French","Italian","Russian","Portuguese","Japanese","Czech","Chinese","Hungarian","Turkish","Polish","Ukrainian","Latino"
>   "01_01_01_01_01","Toma. Te toca.","Here. It's your turn.","Hier. Du bist dran.","Voilà. C'est ton tour.","Ecco. Tocca a te.","Держи. Теперь твоя очередь.","Toma. É a sua vez.","はい。君の番だよ。","Tady. Jsi na řadě.","来吧。轮到你了。","Tessék, te jössz.","Al, Sıra sende.","Masz. Twoja kolej.","Тримай. Твоя черга.","Toma. Te toca."
>   "01_01_01_03_01","Sácame de aquí, por favor.","Get me out of here, please.","Bitte hol mich hier raus.","Sors-moi d'ici, je t'en prie.","Fammi uscire di qui, ti prego.","Вытащи меня отсюда, пожалуйста.","Me tira daqui, por favor.","お願い、ここから出して。","Prosím, dostaň mě odsud.","求求你，带我出去吧。","Szabadíts ki innen, kérlek!","Benİ buradan çıkar, lütfen","Proszę, wydostań mnie stąd.","Витягни мене звiдси, будь ласка.","Sácame de aquí, por favor."

And if you after count, my language (Hungarian) comes after the comma 11.
This maybe help write a good regex for filter out the hungarian strings.

Comment: You would probably be better off importing the file into a database as "comma delimited text" and then either drop the columns you won't need, or export a new file based on a query of the columns you want..

Comment: It would be much easier to do this in Excel.

Comment: @Yorik I tryed, this command is disabled on my server

Comment: @Yorik But you give me a idea, so thx!
http://neocsatblog.info/forditas.php

Comment: It was already in a database? even better, just export!

Comment: @Yorik I'm just now imported, and I can't becouse this function is disabled in my  server, dreamhost.
But here the plain text yuppe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's way too complicated make with a single file editor program.
If you whant to do this, you need a mysql databse, you need to rename the file for for example `file.csv` and after that, import to databse.
Now if you are lucky, you can run this command, and you will be fine:

```
SELECT `COLLUMNAME` FROM `TABLENAME` INTO OUTFILE 'forditas.txt';
```

If you're not, like in my case, becouse this command is disabled on dreamhost server, you can follow this instructions:

1. After you imported a database, you need to make sure charset
   encoding is setted to utf-8, becouse of Latin 2 characters.
2. After that, you need a create php file, for example `translate.php`,
   and on there, paste this to the file:

   ```
     <html>
       <head> 
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <title>Blues and bullets episode 1</title>
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script>
             $(document).ready(function() {
               $(".text-center p:first").remove();
               $("textarea").val($(".text-center p").text()+"<br>");
             });

           </script>
         </head>
   <body>
    <style>
     body{
       background:#eee;
     }
     p{

       font-weight:bold;
     }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="text-center">
      <textarea></textarea>
        <h1 class="jumbatron">Blues and Bullets magyar szöveg Episode 1</h1><br>
        <?php
          $servername = "MYSQLHOST usarly localhost";//Change this!
          $username = "DATABASE USERNAME";//Change this!
          $password = "PASSWORD";//Change this!
          // Create connection
          $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
          $conn->set_charset("utf8");
          // Check connection
          if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
           } 

            $sql = "SELECT `COLLUM` FROM `DATABASENAME`.`TABLE 1`";//Chanche this!

             $result = $conn->query($sql);
             if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                 // output data of each row
                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                   $string =$row["COLLUM"];//Change this!
                   $string = preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/', "\\1\n\\2", $string);
                     echo "<p>".$string."</p>";
                 }
             } else {
                 echo "0 results";
             }
             $conn->close();
        ?><br>
      </div>
    </div>
   ```
3. The next step is, you need the chancge some line in this file.
   I make a comment for everything what you need to chancge but I higlighted here the lines:
   The first thing is the databse connection:

   ```
          $servername = "MYSQLHOST usarly localhost";//Change this!
          $username = "DATABASE USERNAME";//Change this!
          $password = "PASSWORD";//Change this!
   ```

   Please fill out the correct datas.
   After that we have this line:

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT `COLLUM` FROM `DATABASENAME`.`TABLE 1`";//Chanche this!
   ```

   We need the give the collum number, and the database name, and the table name.
   So we basically change everything inside of "`" character.
   One last thing.
   We need to echo out this, so you need to change this line:

   ```
   $string =$row["COLLUM"];//Change this!
   ```

   Change `COLLUM` text to collum real name.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will need the "KEY" column in the file as well to make things work.
This should be entered in the **Replace** dialog before pressing **Replace all**:

```
Find what: ^("[^"]+)(","[^"]+){10}(","[^"]+").*
Replace with: \1\3
```

Remember that this will work only if there is no " characters in any field.

Comment: This regex result is:
"KEY","Hungarian" anything else is deleted, but I need sentese from this text file.

Comment: Are you sure? What you pasted in the question was a CSV but without linebreak. I thought it was a typo and added it. If your file is really ONE SINGLE line, that's why all else disappeared. But then "my language (Hungarian) comes after the comma 11" is not true.

Comment: I'm sure,but maybe youre right in somepoint about linebreak, I have line break on file.
 Look my screenshot:
http://i67.tinypic.com/10ghbsx.png

Comment: But fortunetly I found a solution for this with php:
http://neocsatblog.info/forditas.php